# How to resize a JDialog when it is in undecorated state?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I want to know how to make a JDialog resizable when it has been set `setUndecorated(true);`. Resizing can be done by the outer frame.When it is undecorated, no frame and then the JDialog cannot be resized. How can I resize the JDialog when its outerframe is not available?

Comment: Why would the user even try to resize an undecorated floating window?  Given they are typically not resizable, it probably would never occur to them unless there were big, red, flashing text to the effect "CAN CHANGE MY SIZE!".  I think this GUI has bigger problems than "How?".

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Thanks for your attention. undecorating is used here because I wanted to give some fancy look and make corners round and so few reasons... But still the user should be able to resize the JDialog

Comment: A code snipt which gives a solutions found [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/335891/GUI/java/JDialog-undecorated-but-resizeable)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean how can a user resize an undecorated dialog (as the developer you can always call `setSize`)

The only way this can be done is to implement the logic yourself.

This will require to implement a `MouseListener` and monitor the `mousePressed`, `mouseReleased` and `mouseDragged` events

You need to take into consideration that you probably only want gutter around the dialog that will trigger a resize (say 5 pixels).  It's important that no other components lay within this gutter, as they will override you mouse listener.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found a code snip which you mean as well.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested this, but from what I gather it appears that you just need the following method:

```
// window reszie event
private void _setUpWindowResizeEvent() {
this.addMouseMotionListener(
new MouseMotionListener() {

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
if( mHozResizeEnabled || mVerResizeEnabled ) {
int x = mouseEvent.getX();
int y = mouseEvent.getY();
_resizeWindow(
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation() );
sticky.setSize( getSize() );
_fireStickyUpdated();
}
}
```

Reference:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/JPGroup/message/1877